# Deadlock, update where id=pk_value with different pk_values, figure out reason and how to fix

Tags: mysql, deadlock

How it possible to have such kind of deadlock?
id column is a unique primary key, so no gap to lock. I don't have any other conditions to lock more than one row. It is different rows, how that possible?

I am trying to avoid occuring of such deadlock, so I want to figure out, how separate rows can lock each other and then I will be able to write a fix for my code.

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2023-02-28 19:17:32 0x7f25a546d700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 6666459395, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 9 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 6
MySQL thread id 756067383, OS thread handle 139783855896320, query id 68616695605 localhost 127.0.0.1 name updating
update `balances` set `balance` = `balance` + 10, `balances`.`updated_at` = '2023-02-28 19:17:32' where `id` = 28

*** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 354 page no 4 n bits 128 index PRIMARY of table `name`.`balances` trx id 6666459395 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 5 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 10; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 0000000000000004; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00018d5a1903; asc    Z  ;;
 2: len 7; hex 0200005edd23e8; asc    ^ # ;;
 3: len 8; hex 0000000000000002; asc         ;;
 4: len 2; hex 0283; asc   ;;
 5: len 9; hex 8000000002741cd637; asc      t  7;;
 6: len 7; hex 454e41424c4544; asc ENABLED;;
 7: len 4; hex 6099a78b; asc `   ;;
 8: len 4; hex 63fe534c; asc c SL;;
 9: SQL NULL;


*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 354 page no 4 n bits 128 index PRIMARY of table `name`.`balances` trx id 6666459395 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 29 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 10; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 000000000000001c; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00018d5a190a; asc    Z  ;;
 2: len 7; hex 0200005ec62ea2; asc    ^ . ;;
 3: len 8; hex 000000000000000d; asc         ;;
 4: len 2; hex 0283; asc   ;;
 5: len 9; hex 80000000002132733a; asc      !2s:;;
 6: len 7; hex 454e41424c4544; asc ENABLED;;
 7: len 4; hex 621f8a75; asc b  u;;
 8: len 4; hex 63fe534c; asc c SL;;
 9: SQL NULL;


*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 6666459402, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 9 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 6 row lock(s), undo log entries 7
MySQL thread id 756068626, OS thread handle 139799644845824, query id 68616695708 localhost 127.0.0.1 name updating
update `balances` set `balance` = `balance` + 0.22, `balances`.`updated_at` = '2023-02-28 19:17:32' where `id` = 4

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 354 page no 4 n bits 128 index PRIMARY of table `name`.`balances` trx id 6666459402 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 14 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 10; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 000000000000000d; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00018d5a190a; asc    Z  ;;
 2: len 7; hex 0200005ec62f01; asc    ^ / ;;
 3: len 8; hex 0000000000000007; asc         ;;
 4: len 2; hex 0283; asc   ;;
 5: len 9; hex 80000000007e7bef0b; asc      ~{  ;;
 6: len 7; hex 454e41424c4544; asc ENABLED;;
 7: len 4; hex 60d0a442; asc `  B;;
 8: len 4; hex 63fe534c; asc c SL;;
 9: SQL NULL;

Record lock, heap no 29 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 10; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 000000000000001c; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00018d5a190a; asc    Z  ;;
 2: len 7; hex 0200005ec62ea2; asc    ^ . ;;
 3: len 8; hex 000000000000000d; asc         ;;
 4: len 2; hex 0283; asc   ;;
 5: len 9; hex 80000000002132733a; asc      !2s:;;
 6: len 7; hex 454e41424c4544; asc ENABLED;;
 7: len 4; hex 621f8a75; asc b  u;;
 8: len 4; hex 63fe534c; asc c SL;;
 9: SQL NULL;


*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 354 page no 4 n bits 128 index PRIMARY of table `name`.`balances` trx id 6666459402 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 5 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 10; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 0000000000000004; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00018d5a1903; asc    Z  ;;
 2: len 7; hex 0200005edd23e8; asc    ^ # ;;
 3: len 8; hex 0000000000000002; asc         ;;
 4: len 2; hex 0283; asc   ;;
 5: len 9; hex 8000000002741cd637; asc      t  7;;
 6: len 7; hex 454e41424c4544; asc ENABLED;;
 7: len 4; hex 6099a78b; asc `   ;;
 8: len 4; hex 63fe534c; asc c SL;;
 9: SQL NULL;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for notice, done.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 transactions, one moving 10 from one account to another, and another moving 0.22 between other accounts?

We see 2 of the 4 ids, but we don't see the other two.  I suspect that one of the others was the same as one of these.

Simple rerun the rolled back the transaction.

Also, if you have a `SELECT` as part of the transaction, be sure to include `FOR UPDATE`.